# Datetime object value for null but value still throwing null

Tags: c#

I have a bit of code that checks a table called upload tracker the issue I am having is the if the value of the datetime stored in the db is null it causing this section of code to crash.

```
using (var db = new SOMEntities1())
{
            var uploadTracekerDate = db.UploadTrackers.Where(w => w.TableName == "Stock").FirstOrDefault();


           if (uploadTracekerDate != null)
            {

                string lastUpLoadedDateConvetedTOSage =Convert.ToDateTime(uploadTracekerDate.LastImportedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                var stockwhereClause = string.Format(" and STOCK.RECORD_CREATE_DATE >= '{0}'", lastUpLoadedDateConvetedTOSage);
                stockwhereClause = stockwhereClause + string.Format(" and STOCK.RECORD_MODIFY_DATE >= '{0}'",
                                       lastUpLoadedDateConvetedTOSage);
                sql += stockwhereClause;

            }

}
```

What is the best way of handling this errror as the value seems to trigger a null exception no matter what I use to trap the object being null

Comment: which bit is triggering a null exception? also: I hate to say it, but: concatenating values to create SQL is just ... doomed to all sorts of failure; ideally, this should be parameterized

Comment: it looks to me like the easiest way to cause this would be for `LastImportedDate` to be `null`; what do you want to do in that case? maybe just don't add the extra filter?

Comment: And what are you doing here to prevent a null reference exception? Did you read [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Fildor it was there just not indented correctly now fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code shown, the most likely scenario is that `uploadTracekerDate` is non-null, and is an instance that has `LastImportedDate` as an empty (null) `Nullable<DateTime>` (`DateTime?`).

This means that it is `.Value` that is throwing the exception, so you need to think about what you actually want to do in the scenario when `LastImportedDate` is `null`, and implement that - probably by checking `if (uploadTracekerDate.LastImportedDate.HasValue)` before accessing the `.Value`.

However! And this is important: please please move away from the approach of concatenating strings with values to create SQL - it is a *terrible* idea for multiple reasons; in this case, the most likely problem will be i18n with locale problems, but the same approach can also cause serious SQL injection problems. Whenever possible (which is almost always): prefer SQL parameters.

Comment: your on the money there marc very helpfull twice in a row sir.

Comment: @david well, if either has answered your question - consider pressing the green tick button!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code seems to be wrong.

```
string lastUpLoadedDateConvetedTOSage =Convert.ToDateTime(uploadTracekerDate.LastImportedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

... is missing a closing bracket.

Secondly, try comparing to **DBNull.Value** instead, when using values from an SQL database.

Comment: This is not a scenario where `DBNull` applies - this sounds very much like an ORM scenario with `DateTime?`

Comment: IAlso its not right to create a question when you do not have the rep to comment on a question.